# ggplot2 Boxplot value 0 grid color and line type

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, boxplot

I am wondering how I can change the grid line on x value=0, marked with a cross in the image, in my graph to shows the change from +ive to -ive. I would like to have it marked red with the same thickness. Thank you

=== Updated based on the comment

@Mtoto: My apologies. Here is the script.

```
df.boxplot<- ggplot(melt(df[,c(2:7)]), aes(variable, value)) 
df.boxplot + 
  geom_boxplot(lwd=1.2)+ theme_economist() + scale_colour_economist()+ 
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks=seq(-5, 10, 0.5),name="Linear Measurements (mm)", breaks=seq(-5, 10, 1)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="Black", size=20),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(face="bold", colour="Black", vjust=0.5, size=20)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name="",labels=c("T0 A","T1 B","Δ AB","T0 C","T1 D","Δ CD")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", colour="Black", size=30,margin=margin(0,20,0,0)),
        axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1, size=20)) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="White",size=0.2))+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  ggtitle(" Title")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=25,lineheight=2, hjust =0.5, vjust=0.5, margin = margin(20, 10, 20, 0)))
```

I would also like to add a gap (one x unit/level) between the first three boxplots and the second three boxplots. I tried adding a NA column and use drop=FALSE and it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: example of data and code, no images please

Comment: Even after your update, this is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423). What is `df` in your example? Provide some sample data so we can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at `geom_hline` -- I'm sure this is a duplicate...

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = gl(5, 25),
                 y = rnorm(125))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_hline(aes(y_intercept = 0), color = "red")
```

[image]